# Default values for failed backticks in bash in one command

Tags: bash

I am trying to come up with a mechanism to assign a default value to a variable when a command fails. I can't seem to combine them with `||` or inserting `$()` inside the 2nd line.

How do I convert this to one command?

```
MY_COMMAND=$(which somefile)
MY_COMMAND=${MY_COMMAND:-"/usr/local/dev/branch/somefile"}
```

Comment: The following works for me: `echo "$(which thing || echo 'default')"`, is it what you want? Otherwise, indeed you can't nest parameter substitution in Bash, so 2 lines are needed ;)

Comment: Yes! This works `MYVAR=$(echo "$(which wwget || echo 'you do not have wwget')")` Happy to accept if you post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work in Bash:

```
MY_VARIABLE="$(which thing || echo 'default')"
```

As this is using a [subshell](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html) (`$()` syntax), there should be a complete command on each side of the `||` or symbol. So the second part should `echo` something.

On the opposite, `${}` is used in [parameter substitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html), and the variable names can't be nested.